# Embed connected sum of submanifolds in the ambient manifold

Tags: differential-topology

The book *Differential Manifolds* by Kosinski claimed we can embed the connected sum of two submanifolds of codimension $>1$ into the ambient manifold. I am wondering why we need the extra condition $>1$ at here. At least in dimension 1-3 I could not find a counter example. On the other hand I also do not know how to prove this rigorously enough. So I venture to ask.

Comment: For anyone looking for this statement, it is an exercise at the end of section 1 of chapter VI.